# WebApi How to write Parallel function

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, asp.net-web-api2

Here i'm new to webapi please help me how can i write parallel methode.

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetData()
            {  
    Parallel.Invoke(() => ObjRepo.GetEmployee());    
//Here how can i pass its to ok return type   
                return Ok();
            }
```

Comment: what is the sense in parallel execution if you have to wait for result to return it?

Comment: Generally we write methode as var x=objrepo.GetEmployee() this x we pass as return ok(x);   then we will get data from "x" like that i'm asking

Comment: Do you mean you want to use async/await?

Comment: @john yes i wana to use asyn/await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Task.WhenAll` to execute multiple methods parallel.

> You apply the `Task.WhenAll` method to a collection of tasks. The
>   application of `WhenAll` returns a single task that isn’t complete until
>   every task in the collection is completed. The tasks appear to run in
>   parallel, but no additional threads are created. The tasks can
>   complete in any order.

Following is a sample code

```
   var method1Task = Method1Async();
   var method2Task = Method2Async();
   await Task.WhenAll(method1Task, method1Task);
```

You methods should look like

```
  public async Task Method1Async()
        {
          //Implementation 
        }
  public async Task Method2Async()
        {
         //Implemenation
        }
```

For more details you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-extend-the-async-walkthrough-by-using-task-whenall)